# "all diejenigen" - Wieso wird das rausgekürzte [e] nicht mit einem Apostroph ersetzt?

Tags: etymology, apostrophe

Ich habe mir gerade die Frage gestellt, warum bei

> ... all diejenigen ...

sowohl das "e" bei "alle" rausgekürzt wurde - und dabei nicht einmal ein Apostroph gesetzt wird, also beispielsweise: "all' diejenigen" [falsch].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "all"

existiert als eigenständiges Pronomen/Zahlwort laut Duden, was sehr wahrscheinlich die Ursache dafür ist, dass bei:

> ... all diejenigen ...

kein Apostroph gesetzt wird.

Link: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/all

Answer (score 4):

Ich zitiere aus https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/all:

> Das Indefinitum *all, alle, alle* kann mit nachfolgenden Pronomen in Verbindung treten. Die Personalendung von all findet sich dann im Pronomen wieder:
>
> *Warum musst du all dies**e** Vorwürfe an mich richten?*

Daher:

> diejenigen Leute
>   alle Leute

aber:

> all diejenigen Leute

Comment: Danke schön für fundierte Erklärung :)